# Explanation for having Regex Match Group no error

Tags: c#, regex

We're a bit confused why this piece of code doesn't throw any error as we're expecting for an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+)");
Match result = re.Match("123456789");
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1000000000].Value);
```

Can anyone explain any thoughts about his?

Comment: And `result.Groups[10000]` isn't null as well? What is the output?

Comment: Yeah. A value of `string.Empty` was its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groups is not an array, it's indexed property. It's can return anything depends on it's code.

```
public Group this[int groupnum] { get; }
```

UPD From MSDN:

> You can determine the number of items in the collection by retrieving
>   the value of the Count property. Valid values for the groupnum
>   parameter range from 0 to one less than the number of items in the
>   collection.
>
> The GroupCollection object returned by the Match.Groups property
>   always has at least one member. If the regular expression engine
>   cannot find any matches in a particular input string, the single Group
>   object in the collection has its Group.Success property set to false
>   and its Group.Value property set to String.Empty.
>
> If groupnum is not the index of a member of the collection, or if
>   groupnum is the index of a capturing group that has not been matched
>   in the input string, the method returns a Group object whose
>   **Group.Success property is false and whose Group.Value property is
>   String.Empty**.

Comment: -1 OP is asking WHY, Not HOW. Even an array indexing is translated into some code, you know. It could've been translated into a different code. This is not an answer.

Comment: Turns into a +1 after update. Now we might not have the developer's reasons, but we do have documentation that explains usage.

Comment: I found that remarks with its MSDN documentation, still I'm confused why. Until you explained indexed property which justified me about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would just chalk this up to an implementation choice.

[GroupCollection.Item Property (Int32) documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25kfx75y.aspx) does not indicate that it throws any exceptions: even `-1` works:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+)");
Match result = re.Match("123456789");
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1000000000].Value); // works: ""
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[0].Value); // works: "123456789"
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[-1].Value); // works: ""
```

Contrast this with [DataColumnCollection.Item Property (Int32) documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb313x8d.aspx), which indicates it can throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A"));
DataColumn existent = dt.Columns[0]; // works
DataColumn nonexistent = dt.Columns[1]; // doesn't work - IndexOutOfRangeException
```

Maybe someone can provide insight into the reason(s) `GroupCollection` handles nonsense without an exception and `DataColumnCollection` handles the same nonsense with an exception, but I suspect it is little different than how each of us might elect to write a simple string-contains method (setting aside BCL support for this already):

```
bool StringContains(string inString, string lookForString)
{
    if (inString.IsNullOrEmpty)
        return false;

    // blah
}
```

vs.

```
bool StringContains(string inString, string lookForString)
{
    if (inString == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("inString");
    if (inString.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("inString cannot be empty.");

    // blah
}
```